# Accept a certificate in Pageload in chrome in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am using the below code to Accept the Ceriticates on Pageload while launching chrome but then also it is not accepting the ceritificates and hence its stuck on the Accept certificate Popup.

please help

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--start-maximized"));
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    capabilities.setCapability("AcceptUntrustedCertificates", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--ignore-certificate-errors"));



    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

please use the below URL for image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Hwt.png
whenever i navigate.to(">>>>>>");
this popup comes wich i am not able to handle

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the popup? Try some image hosting site.

Comment: sure.please find the image in the below URL http://i.imgur.com/QNUnYuO.png?1

Answer (score 0):

`--ignore-certificate` is deprecated. Use `--test-type` for testing purposes.

Anyway, this works for me:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "/path/to/chromedriver.exe");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```